# How to get the the greatest number and its index from a list?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find the greatest number from my list and also its index.
For example this is my list:

```
list = [4.3,0.0,6.2214,9.1,1.023990433763,3.839]
```

I can find the greatest number with this line:

```
greatest = maximum list
```

In this example, the greatest number is 9.1, but how can I display its index (in the example, 3)?

Comment: Try implementing a recursive approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to explicitly annotate the list with indices, then do the search there.

```
Prelude> zip [4.3,0.0,6.2214,9.1,1.023990433763,3.839] [0..]
[(4.3,0),(0.0,1),(6.2214,2),(9.1,3),(1.023990433763,4),(3.839,5)]
```

Because tuples `Ord` lexicographically, you can actually simply use `maximum` on that list:

```
Prelude> maximum $ zip [4.3,0.0,6.2214,9.1,1.023990433763,3.839] [0..]
(9.1,3)
```

This is a bit hackish though because you still have at least in principle also a comparison on the index, which you don't really want. So a cleaner way is

```
> :m +Data.List Data.Ord
> maximumBy (comparing fst) $ zip [4.3,0.0,6.2214,9.1,1.023990433763,3.839] [0..]
(9.1,3)
```

Of course, if in the end you want *only* the index, you can easily throw away the value:

```
> snd . maximumBy (comparing fst) $ zip [4.3,0.0,6.2214,9.1,1.023990433763,3.839] [0..]
3
```